# Do all webforms controls encode HTML?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to audit my legacy WebForms app for XSS vulnerability. Being a WebForms app, it mostly writes content to the page via controls, TextBox, Label, etc, plus the `<% ... %>` syntax.

My question is: do all controls encode HTML, so that I know that anything like `<asp:SomeControl ... >` is safe, or are there some controls that do not, and which require manual, explicit encoding? And, is there any other way that text can get on the page in WebForms without being encoded?

I'm not talking about actual HTML or rich text editor controls here, just conventional text display controls.

Comment: Simple answer is no, `<asp:Literal>` does what it says on the tin, it will literally render as provided

Comment: Ah, so that is a clear exception. But are there any others?

Comment: i'm not sure if it changed over the years but which version of asp.net (visual studio)?

Comment: The latest, ASP.NET 4.5 and VS 2013 (soon to be VS 2015).

Answer (score 0):

i don't think encoding is done automatically in either direction for most if not any controls.
[Securing Standard Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178270%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: i hope that helps. it's hard to tell if you're asking about the controls' outputs or a combination of ctrl + user input, etc. anyway, that article has a lot of good links if it's not quite right.

Comment: The control output. If the user provided HTML, it should be encoded **unless** it's a rich text control, in which case we need to make sure there's no dangerous markup.